# Example of an infinite balanced nonabelian group

Tags: group-theory

> A group is called a *balanced* group provided that, for all $a,b \in G$, either $ab=ba$ or $a^2=b^2$.

Example of (possibly infinite) balanced groups are abelian groups. An example of a finite balanced nonabelian group is the Quaternion group.

Does it exist an infinite balanced nonabelian group?

Comment: Yes, $Q_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_2^\omega$ is balanced, where $Q_8$ is the quaternion group of order $8$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2^\omega$ is the direct sum of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @Jim: Oh yes you're right! Why didn't I think about such a simple example? Thanks.

Comment: A related, follow-up question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43595/which-are-the-infinite-balanced-nonabelian-groups

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, $Q_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_2^\omega$ is balanced, where $Q_8$ is the quaternion group of order $8$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2^\omega$ is the direct sum of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 7):

As Jim Belk has quite rightly pointed out, there do exist infinite non-abelian examples. However, there do not exist any infinite *finitely generated* examples of non-abelian balanced groups.

Proof:

Suppose $G$ is non-abelian, balanced, infinite, and finitely generated. Group elements are either central or non-central (obviously), and the non-central ones square to some fixed element, $u$ say. As groups do not contain non-trivial idempotents (elements such that $e^2=e$), one has that $u \in Z(G)$.

Noting that for $x$ some non-central generator, $xu\not\in Z(G)$ so $u=(xu)^2=u^3$ and so $u^2=1$. Further, $uw^2=u$ for all $w\in Z(G)$, by the same logic. Thus, $W^2=u$ for all $W\in G\setminus Z(G)$ while $W^2=1$ for all $W \in Z(G)$.

Therefore, every element has order either 2 or 4. One can either plow on ahead (I don't think it is too hard, but it is a tad tedious) to prove the problem outright, or one can apply an early result about Burnsides Problem: a finitely generated group in which each element has order a divisor of 4 is finite*. Ta-da!

*[here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/188968/35478) is a link to a MathOverflow question about where to find a proof of this.